# PHP If and Else booleans connected with my API don't work

Tags: php, if-statement

So, I'm working on a code with an API, and I have to do an if else with the response of a function that returns a boolean.
When testing in Postman, it returns true and falsde depending of the conditions, but when I try using my code, it refuses to work:

```
if ($response):
    echo "exist";
    //header("Location: LogIn.html");
else:
    echo "doesnt exist";
    //header("Location: RompePalabras.php");
endif;
curl_close($curl);
```

Whenever I test it out, it always echoes "Exist, even tho when I echo the response, it tells me if its true or false.

Comment: _"when I echo the response, it tells me if its true or false"_ - Can you do `var_dump($result);` and add the result to your question? If you echo a boolean, it won't output "true" or "false", it would give you "1" for true and nothing for false.

Comment: try print_r(is_bool($response));

Comment: Most likely you're not receiving a boolean but rather the string `true` or `false` when you call your API. This means you're using a string which is always truthy if it's not empty. Try to use `var_dump($response)` and look in your network tab, so you can tell the difference. We can't really say more from your lack of code.